# Selecting multiple elements in jQuery doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

Currently, I have this jQuery code:

```
jQuery("#slideshow article").removeClass("current").removeAttr("class").eq(idx).addClass("current");
jQuery("#slideshow nav a").removeClass("current").removeAttr("class").eq(idx).addClass("current");
```

As you can see, they're totally identical, except the selector. I've tried to combine them these ways:

```
jQuery("#slideshow article, #slideshow nav a").removeClass("current").removeAttr("class").eq(idx).addClass("current");
```

(which selects only the first selector)

This:

```
jQuery("#slideshow article", "#slideshow nav a").removeClass("current").removeAttr("class").eq(idx).addClass("current");
```

(which causes the slideshow to stop working, even though it doesn't throw an error as far as I can tell)

And this:

```
jQuery("#slideshow article").add("#slideshow nav a").removeClass("current").removeAttr("class").eq(idx).addClass("current");
```

Still doesn't work. I've tried to Google the issue, and to read similar questions on StackOverflow without luck. Can anybody help?

**EDIT:** [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/33ueJ/) that works fine until combining (.current on `<nav>` should get blue)

Comment: Any chance you can make a fiddle of it?

Comment: Fiddle works fine, see: http://jsfiddle.net/cF2Tt/  -- You should check your console for errors, possibly problem with eq(idx)

Comment: you can't combine the queries once you use ***eq(idx)***. The `idx` is right for each query ***separately*** but after combining, it is just right for the first, and wrong for the second.

Comment: @Patrick, I've made a fiddle now.

Comment: @KingKing, thanks, didn't know that, what should I do, then? Have them separately, or is there a way?

Comment: @SimenMangseth if you want one line query, you may have to try using `:eq()` selector, however the query is also a bit long (of course is still shorter than the 2 separate queries), check this http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/cF2Tt/2/ (your demo does not have any `nav` element, looks like it's not complete to show the problem)

Comment: @King King: The nav elements are added by the carousel. It was shorter to use an `:nth-child` filter on the entire list. Answer below.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie not sure about the exact HTML structure of the OP, but as in my demo code, we can use `:nth-of-type`, `:nth-child` won't work.

Comment: @King King: The structure just happens to have the elements at the same level under one parent for each set, so nth-child does work. The other bug was just me forgetting nth-child is 1-based (not 0-based like all the other indexing selectors) :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie I meant using `:nth-child` in my demo code does not work, here you see http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/cF2Tt/3/ , and here is how it should be (when using `nth-of-type` instead) http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/cF2Tt/4/ (I said ***as in my demo code*** in the previous comment).

Comment: @King King: Yes, your demo HTML is not the same as the SO, so nth-child will not work with your demo code. It does however work for the question asked. Handy to have alternatives for other situations though. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Cause:

The problem is that each of your selectors creates a single jQuery collection, then indexes a particular element *from that collection* using `eq()`. If you combine multiple selectors you are only building one list, so `eq()` will always return only one element.

*What you really wanted was a selector that cares about the element's index within its group.*

### Answer:

As each group of selections happen to be under a single parent, you can do it with an <kbd>[:nth-child()](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/)</kbd> filter:

```
jQuery("#slideshow article, #slideshow nav a").removeAttr("class").filter(':nth-child(' + (idx+1) + ')').addClass("current");
```

**The most important thing to remember is that nth-child, unlike other indexing selectors, is 1-based, not 0-based. This is so that it matches the CSS nth-child equivalent**

### JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/33ueJ/4/

*Note: *as you are removing the class attribute completely, you do not need to remove the class first*.

**Addendum:**

And as King King points out, in comment, if another HTML structure did not support using <kbd>[nth-child()](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/)</kbd>, you can always use <kbd>[nth-of-type()](http://api.jquery.com/nth-of-type-selector/)</kbd> (so long as the two groups of elements are different element types.

Comment: have you tried selecting the article manually by clicking on one of the circles? It works perfectly in the OP's demo code but it does not work in your demo. I've not looked into the code but that's just the issue worth noting about.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Thanks for your elaborate explanation. However, another side-effect on both of your fiddles, is that first they go to the first slide, then the second without problems (as expected), but then it goes to white for 5 seconds instead of going to the third slide, and then it goes to the first slide again.

Comment: @Simen Mangseth: Forgot the most basic rule with `nth-child`... it is a 1-based index to match CSS nth-child. Code sorted. Cheers